# Php on csv and Jquery Datatable

Tags: php, jquery, csv, datatable

I struggling with a problem for a day but could not come up with a good idea how to handle the following: I have a parsed CSV file what I'm rendering in a Jquery datatable. To each row is appended a checkbox. If rows are selected and submitted, the selected lines from CSV file should be deleted. My problem is how to give an id to CSV lines what would be unique even if a row is deleted or others are added. Should be managed with PHP or there would be a better solution with Jquery?

Answer (score 0):

I'd dump the csv to a temporary database table that had an auto_increment primary key. Then the db takes care of maintaining state. Your jQuery datatable would have a hidden column to hold the primary key which acts as a unique identifier for each row.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I have been playing with the idea, but I don't really know if has sense to save my logs in a table. I thought it can be fixed somehow with php file commands. But anyway your idea is easier to implement till now.

Comment: I found in the php documentation a usefull example what can be used $row = 1;
$f = fopen("../logs/logfile.csv", "r");
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {    
     $num = count($line);
     echo "<tr><td class='center'><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value='$row'></td>
        <td class='center'>$row</td>";
        $row++;
        foreach ($line as $cell) {        
            echo "<td>".htmlspecialchars($cell)."</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
}
fclose($f);

Comment: @lgt: where you store your data, whether temp file or temp table, doesn't really matter.  I use a temp table for 2 reasons: 1) I usually have a db attached to the app I'm working on, and 2) most db's already know how to parse a csv and then I have access to powerful relational operations instead of having to do everything with a php loop.